# Can I measure my Chinese proficiency without taking an HSK test?

Tags: resource-request, chinese, electronic-resources, exams

Is it possible to measure my proficiency on Mandarin Chinese without taking an HSK exam?

I recently took a brief exam on [EasyMandarin website](http://www.easymandarin.cn/test-your-chinese-level/beginner-online-mandarin-level-test/) but it is only about a brief grammar and vocabulary test, where you are expected to fill in the blank in a sentence by picking one of the four words. This is more like a quick test to introduce the respondents to their own programs.

[The ESL test](https://www.esl-languages.com/en/study-abroad/online-tests/chinese-test/index.htm) is the same in this respect.

I can't take the HSK exam right now, so is there any reliable website to test my Mandarin proficiency online?

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning!

Comment: @fi12 Thanks. Is this kind of question suitable here? I thought I post it on Chinese language SE.

Comment: This is an on-topic question for this site, and I'm sure you'll receive an answer to your question soon.

Comment: Since you mention HSK, I assume you're interested in simplified Chinese characters only, and not in traditional Chinese characters?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Right, and I don’t understand traditional Chinese characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [page on Emory University's website about HSK Sample Tests](http://confucius.emory.edu/hsk_and_resources/hsk/hsk_samples.html) should be of use to you. There are 6 different sample tests, along with a relevant review of vocabulary and grammar.

Unfortunately, I'm not fluent in Mandarin, so I can't check if the practice tests are in the form that you prefer. If they aren't, please let me know so I can find a better resource.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that this is either a real test that was conducted in the past, or a mock that is designed for students taking it before the actual exam. The 6 tests correspond to each level, so you can take it only once for each level...

Answer (score 2):

If the base language needs to be English (or Chinese), the options are rather limited. Besides the tests you have already found, there are the following:

- LanguageTrainers: [Chinese (Mandarin) Language Level Test characters](https://www.languagetrainers.com/chinese-characters-level-test.php): a free online test with multiple-choice question.
- The tests offered by LTI (Language Trainers International), which are not free. The [types of tests](https://www.languagetesting.com/lti-information/general-test-descriptions) they offer include an "Oral Proficiency Interview" (over the phone) and an "Oral Proficiency Interview – Computer (OPIc)". For the other tests you probably need to go to a test centre. Since they offer [Chinese language testing](https://www.languagetesting.com/chinese-language-testing/), I assume that the above tests are also available for Chinese.

Since fi12 mentioned HSK sample tests, I would like to add that many HSK preparation books also contain sample tests. These can help you check whether you are ready for HSK. However, it is important to bear in mind that the HSK-to-CEFR correspondence table provided by HanBan is misleading. For the actual CEFR levels, see [my webpage about learning Chinese](http://cstrobbe.github.io/languagelearning/chinese/index.html#hsk).